# Generate list of 'almost' random tuples

Tags: python, list, random, tuples, list-comprehension

Let's say that list 'l' contains tuples and has an even number of elements.
Every tuple consists of 3 numbers (int) 0 <= x <= 255

And now the fun part, there is a following pattern:

```
l[0] = l[1], l[2] = l[3], l[4] = l[5] .....
```

So the list looks for example like this:

```
l[0] = (100, 200, 10)

l[1] = (100, 200, 10)

l[2] = (250, 45, 30)

l[3] = (250, 45, 30)

l[4] = (30, 10, 5)

l[5] = (30, 10, 5)
```

.......

The problem is not how to generate the list because that's easy, I want to know if there is any way to do it in one line, using some smart tricks and list comprehension etc.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
from random import randint
b = []
for _ in range(4):
    b += [(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))]*2

# example for how b looks:
# [(206, 89, 40), (206, 89, 40), (36, 115, 91), (36, 115, 91), (232, 55, 96), (232, 55, 96), (183, 114, 179), (183, 114, 179)]
```

Comment: Will you give your actual code?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I don't understand what your pattern is supposed to be, other than some of them being equal.

Comment: @khelwood: From my understanding, OP wants the consecutive ones to be equal

Comment: @RahulAgarwal No, if consecutive ones were equal, they'd have to _all_ be equal. I can see each odd-indexed tuple is equal to the one that preceded it, but is that it? Are the values arbitrary?

Comment: Why does it need to be a one liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double loop in the list comprehension:

```
b = [value for _ in range(4)
     for value in [(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))] * 2]
```